# NestJs/Mongoose Multiple schemas for same model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, nestjs

I was wandering if there is a way to have multiple schemas for the same model. In one of my modules I have two different schemas that are trying to access the same model. But when I do this:

```
@Module({
   imports: [
      MongooseModule.forFeature([
         {name: 'foo', schema: Schema1},
         {name: 'foo', schema: Schema2},
   ]), ......
```

I get the error `Cannot overwrite 'foo' model once compiled`

Here is an example of schemas I have:

```
export class Schema1{
   type: { type: string, index: true, default: 'someValue'},
   data: {mapname: string}
}
export class Schema2{
   type: {type: string, index: true, default: 'anotherValue'}.
   data: {showStats: boolean, email: string}
}
```

Comment: But how would it know which model to use? When you inject the model into a schema it is referenced by name `@InjectModel('foo')` and that would be ambiguous. How do you want to decide which schema should be used? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I finally realised that the naming was just used to create a "link" between the `MongooseModule` and the `InjectModel` inside the service. I thought it had to be the same as the name of the Collection.

Comment: Maybe add this as an answer and accept it. It is frustrating for people spending time on an unanswered question and then find out it has already been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a model for example in a service, it is only referenced by name `@InjectModel('foo')` and hence must be unambiguous. You cannot define two models with the same name.

As you said, it is possible however to have two models point to the same collection, as the collection name is an optional parameter, see [source code](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/blob/c173cceac44807edfd0c3284c4991fba02e77a48/lib/mongoose.module.ts#L22):

```
static forFeature(
  models: { name: string; schema: any; collection?: string }[] = [],
  connectionName: string = DefaultDbConnectionToken,
)
```